# Most orthodox way of splitting matrix and list in Python

Tags: python, list, matrix, vector, split

If I have ratios to split a dataset into training, validation, and test sets, what is the most orthodox and elegant way of doing this in Python?

For instance, I split my data into 60% training, 20% testing, and 20% validation.  I have 1000 rows of data with 10 features each, and a label vector of size 1000.  The training set matrix should be of size (600, 10), and so on.

If I create new matrices of features and lists of labels, it wouldn't be memory efficient right? Lets say I did something like this:

```
TRAIN_PORTION = int(datasetSize * tr)
VALIDATION_PORTION = int(datasetSize * va)

# Whatever is left will be for testing
TEST_PORTION = datasetSize - TRAIN_PORTION - VALIDATION_PORTION
trainingSet = dataSet[0, TRAIN_PORTION:]
validationSet = dataSet[TRAIN_PORTION,
                   TRAIN_PORTION + VALIDATIONPORTION:]
testSet = dataset[TRAIN_PORTION+VALIATION_PORTION, datasetSize:]
```

That would leave me with the double amount of used memory, right?

Sorry for the incorrect Python syntax, and thank you for any help.

Comment: yes, doing that what you have done will double the amount of used memory, but if your matrix is only `(1000,10)` I don't think it will be a large problem. Have you run into memory issues?

Comment: Hmm well not really yet. But t I know that I eventually, as I have learned how to use Python, will use datasets that has about 100k entries and maybe 100 features each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct: you will double the memory usage that way.  To avoid doubling the memory usage, you need to do one of two things:

- Release the memory from one sub-matrix before you create the next; this reduces your memory high-water mark to 1.6x the main matrix;
- Write your processing routines to stop at the proper row, always working on the original matrix.

You can achieve the first one by passing list slices to your processing routines, such as

model_test(data_set[:TRAIN_PORTION])

Remember, when you refer to a slice, the interpreter will build a temporary object that results from the given limits.

---

**RESPONSE TO OP COMMENT**

The reference I gave you *does* create a new list.  To avoid using more memory, pass the *entire* list and the desired limits, such as

```
process_function(data_set, 0, TRAIN_PORTION)
process_function(data_set, TRAIN_PORTION, 
                           TRAIN_PORTION + VALIDATION_PORTION)
process_function(data_set, 
                 TRAIN_PORTION + VALIDATION_PORTION,  
                 len(data_set))
```

If you want to do this with just list slices, then please explain where you're having trouble, and why the various pieces of documentation and the tutorials aren't satisfying your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So, if I understand you correctly one possibility is to not create any new matrix or list but rather pass them with correct indexing instead. Would you mind helping me with the other two sets aswell? I mean, how would I pass the data_set[] for the validation and testing portions in a similiar fashion like you wrote for the training portion? Thank you!

Comment: Your response in the edit is perfect, tank you again. I had a hard time finding this information in any documentation so probabily I did not search good enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you would use numpy-arrays (your code actually looks like that), it's possible to use *views* (memory is shared). It's not always easy to understand which operation results in a view and which does not. [Here are some hints](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html).

Short example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(size=(1000, 10))
b = a[:600]
print (b.flags['OWNDATA'])
# False

print(b[3,2])
# 0.373994992467 (some random-val)

a[3,2] = 88888888

print(b[3,2])
# 88888888.0

print(a.shape)
# (1000, 10)
print(b.shape)
# (600, 10)
```

This will probably allow you to do some in-place shuffle at the beginning and then use those linear-segments of your data to obtain views of train, val, test.